# Unit testing HTTP requests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, http, mocks

I would like to unit test my web requests, so on top of my head I came up with the solution below.

Since it seems to be working fine, I'm posting it on this site. Though it doesn't feel very dynamic, I would like your input. For example, this solution can't simulate response headers, which I'm also interested in mocking:

```
public interface IWebRequest
{
    Task<string> DownloadString();
}

public class RealWebRequest : IWebRequest
{
    private readonly string url;

    public RealWebRequest(string url)
    {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Task<string> DownloadString()
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            return client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(url));
        }
    }
}

public class FakeWebRequest : IWebRequest
{
    private readonly string fakeReponse;

    public FakeWebRequest(string fakeReponse)
    {
        this.fakeReponse = fakeReponse;
    }

    public Task<string> DownloadString()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => fakeReponse);
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    private readonly IWebRequest request;

    public TestClass(IWebRequest request)
    {
        this.request = request;
    }

    public async Task<string> DoStuff()
    {
        return await request.DownloadString();
    }
}
```

"Real" usage example:

```
IWebRequest realRequest = new RealWebRequest("http://www.test.com");
TestClass test = new TestClass(realRequest);
string realResult = await test.DoStuff();
```

Unit test usage example:

```
IWebRequest fakeRequest = new FakeWebRequest("fake response string");
TestClass test = new TestClass(fakeRequest);
string fakeResponse = await test.DoStuff();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I really rather think you have the right idea with the interface and your real class. I do heartily endorse your use of `readonly` which doesn't get a lot of exposure. However, there are many good mocking frameworks out there that you don't need to write your own fake class to unit test with. For instance, we use [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4) where I work and your unit test example would look like this:

```
Mock<IWebRequest> fakeRequest = new Mock<IWebRequest>();

fakeRequest
    .Setup(request => request.DownloadString(It.IsAny<string>())
    .Returns("fake response string");

TestClass test = new TestClass(fakeRequest.Object);
string fakeResponse = await test.DoStuff();
```

Comment: I was under the impression that httprequests were hard to mock using Moq. You have proven me wrong :) Thanks!